# Why wont my calculator function complete the math?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hi so I'm having trouble figuring out why my function will do the division but leave the multiplication as an array without completing the math. Here's the code:

```js
const mathObj = {
      "*": function(a , b) {return a * b},
      "/": function(a , b) {return a / b},
      "+": function(a , b) {return a + b},
      "-": function(a , b) {return a - b}
    }

    const arr = [ 10, "/" , 2 , "*" , 10 , "/" , 2 ];

    function solveTheMath(arr) {

 
      const len = arr.length;

      for(let i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
    
          if(arr[i] === "/" || arr[i] === "*"){

            const sliced = arr.slice(i - 1 , i + 2);
     
            var mathResult = mathObj[arr[i]](sliced[0], sliced[2]);
     
            arr.splice(i - 1 , 3, mathResult);
            console.log(arr);
            //[5*5]

        }
      }
    }
    solveTheMath(arr);
```

Why doesn't the multiplication work but the division does?

Comment: Is this later going to be a prompt for inputting the math function? Or do you plan on always manually populating your array?

Comment: I plan on manually populating the array with click event listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial answer, while it did solve the issue, wasn't that correct. You wanted to use an iterative approach by the look of things (i.e. using a loop to navigate through the initial array and solve all operations before returning the result).

So I replied to you:

> Both operations work, the problem is that you're only calling `solveTheMath` once.
>
> You need to call your function again to solve the array you have constructed. If the constructed array is made of only one element that means the process has reached the end of the computing, you can, therefore, return the first (and only element) of the array.
>
> You are solving the problem in a recursive manner:
>
> ```js
> const mathObj = {
>   "*": function(a , b) {return a * b},
>   "/": function(a , b) {return a / b},
>   "+": function(a , b) {return a + b},
>   "-": function(a , b) {return a - b}
> }
>
> const arr = [ 10, "/" , 2 , "*" , 10 , "/" , 2 ];
>
> function solveTheMath(arr) {
>
>
>   const len = arr.length;
>   
>   for(let i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
>
>       if(arr[i] === "/" || arr[i] === "*"){
>
>         const sliced = arr.slice(i - 1 , i + 2);
>         var mathResult = mathObj[arr[i]](sliced[0], sliced[2]);
>
>         arr.splice(i - 1 , 3, mathResult);
>         
>         if(arr.length == 1) {
>           return arr[0];            // <- no more calculations needed, return result
>         } else {
>           return solveTheMath(arr); // <- more calculations needed, call it again
>         };
>         
>
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> console.log(solveTheMath(arr))
> ```

But actually that isn't correct, you can use both approaches: recursive and iterative to solve this problem. My initial answer provided a poor solution: I kept your `for` loop and called the function again to solve the remaining operations that were in the array. That wasn't necessary because the `for` loop only looped to find the second item and stopped. Anyway, here's a clearer answer, highlighting both approaches.

**Note:** I have renamed `solveTheMath` to `calculate` and `mathObj` to `operations`.

---

### Iterative approach

That's the approach you went for with your question. Because you are using a `for` loop to calculate all operations on a single function call (so the function isn't calling itself over and over).

I recommend using a `while` loop for this because **you will have a hard time looping `arr` when it gets modified (you are replacing three elements with one on each loop).

I'll take the array `[10, "/", 2, "*", 10, "/", 2]` as the starting array to show the process step by step. You can solve the first operation of the provided array. For example, given: , `calculate` will calculate the first operation here: `10, "/", 2`

While the array contains more than one element we will do the following:

1. the first three elements of the array contain: two factors and an operator sign. By slicing the array we can extract those values and save them. I'm using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make it more verbose:

   ```
   const [a, operator, b] = arr.slice(0, 3);
   ```

   here `a = 10`, `operator = "/"` and `b = 2`
2. we will calculate the result of this operation with this line:

   ```
   const result = operations[operator](a, b);
   ```

   `result = 5` (cf: `10 / 2`)
3. then replace the first three elements of the array with the integer `result`:

   ```
   arr.splice(0, 3, result);
   ```

   at this point, `arr` is equal to `[5, "*", 10, "/", 2]`
4. The block has been executed, the `while` condition is checked again. `arr` does contain more than one element so the block is executed again. Remember, at this point `arr` is equal to `[5, "*", 10, "/", 2]`, **not** to `[10, "/", 2, "*", 10, "/", 2]` (we are making progress in the calculation).
5. At the end of the second loop we have `arr` that is equal to `[50, "/", 2]`.
6. A loop after that it is equal to `[25]`.
7. The `while` condition isn't met anymore because `arr` only contains one element, the `while` loop has stopped and the result can be returned.

```js
const operations = {
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b,
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b
}

const calculate = arr => {

  while(arr.length > 1) {  // <- while there are calculations to be done, repeat this block
  
    const [a, operator, b] = arr.slice(0, 3);
    const result = operations[operator](a, b);
  
    arr.splice(0, 3, result);
  
  }

  return arr[0];   // <- no more operations to be done, return result

}

console.log(calculate(
  [10, "/", 2, "*", 10, "/", 2]
));
```

---

### Recursive approach

We can use a recursive approach: the function will only calculate the first operation of the provided array and return a new array with the result of this first operation.

Here is an example:

1. Same as in the iterative array, given the input `[10, "/", 2, "*", 10, "/", 2]` we will first take the first two factors and operator sign by slicing the array. Then we will calculate the result of the operation. Finally, we'll replace the first three elements of the array with this result:

   ```
   const [a, operator, b] = arr.slice(0, 3);
   const result = operations[operator](a, b);
   arr.splice(0, 3, result);
   ```
2. then we check the length of this array:

   1. if it contains only one element, it can be returned
   2. else if it doesn't (in our case) we call the function again (this time on `[5, "*", 10, "/", 2]`).
3. So the function runs again with a new input and `arr` becomes `[50, "/", 2]` which has more than one element so the function needs to be called again (with `[50, "/", 2]` as input)
4. Now, `arr` is `[25]` it only contains one element, the result can be returned (`25`).

```js
const operations = {
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b,
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b
}

const calculate = arr => {

  const [a, operator, b] = arr.slice(0, 3);
  const result = operations[operator](a, b);
  
  arr.splice(0, 3, result);
  
  if (arr.length == 1) {
  
    return arr[0];           // <- no more calculations needed, return result
  
  } else {
  
    return calculate(arr);   // <- more calculations needed, call it again
  
  }

}

console.log(calculate(
  [10, "/", 2, "*", 10, "/", 2]
));
```

---

### Going further...

You can see both methods are quite similar: the main process is the same but the way they handle the end of execution is different. In this case, both are reasonable to use. The iterative approach may seem more natural to you at first. However remember that recursion can allow you to solve more complicated problems. For example, if you would like to implement a kind parenthesis system in your function:

How would you go about calculating: `10*(2+2)/2`? `calculate([10, "*", 2, "+", 2, "/", 2])` would obviously return `11`...

Take the input `[[10, "+", 2], "/", 2]` instead, that makes more sense! How can we calculate the correct result?

Well with our recursive approach this can be implemented quite easily: if `a` or/and `b` are arrays then we reassign them by calling `calculate` on them. That's all:

```
if(a.constructor == Array) {
  a = calculate(a);
}
if(b.constructor == Array) {
  b = calculate(b);
}
```

```js
const operations = {
  "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  "/": (a, b) => a / b,
  "+": (a, b) => a + b,
  "-": (a, b) => a - b
}

const calculate = arr => {

  let [a, operator, b] = arr.slice(0, 3);
  if(a.constructor == Array) {
    a = calculate(a);
  }
  if(b.constructor == Array) {
    b = calculate(b);
  }
  
  const result = operations[operator](a, b);
  
  arr.splice(0, 3, result);
  
  if (arr.length == 1) {
  
    return arr[0];           // <- no more calculations needed, return result
  
  } else {
  
    return calculate(arr);   // <- more calculations needed, call it again
  
  }

}

console.log(calculate(
  [[10, "+", 2], "/", 2]
));
```

Adding those two `if` blocks in the while loop of the iterative approach would have worked. But then you would be left with a... recursive function. That's why you may want to go straight off with the recursive approach. That allows you to expand your code more easily.

---

### More reference on recursion

- [Recursion in JavaScript](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/recursion-in-javascript-1608032c7a1f), freecodecamp.org
- [How factorial's recursive implementation works](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/CPT-Recursion-Factorial-Code.svg), wikimedia
- [Understanding recursive functions in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@zfrisch/understanding-recursion-in-javascript-992e96449e03), medium.com
- [Scope and the function stack: recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion), MDN web docs

Comment: Ah thank you so much.  I'm quite a noob at javascript what does recursive manner mean ?

Comment: @MichaelLewell [Recursion: An act of a function calling itself.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion). when calling `solveTheMath` you are constructing a new array that needs to be calculated too. Therefore you have to call the function again this time on the new array. It will call itself until the array has one element and one only. You may want to look at easier examples on the internet. That will help you understand the concept better.

Comment: @MichaelLewell, I'll edit my answer with a detailed explanation

Comment: @MichaelLewell, Here it is as promised: a ***detailed*** explanation.

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation.  There is just one part that I can't seem to understand.  In my original code I searched for a division or multiplication and then  spliced the index prior the operator index and the index after.  However, in your suggested code,  the index 0 - 2 is being spliced. How does it know to target the nested array through the two if statements?  does "a" equate to a nested array and the same for "b" ?

Comment: @MichaelLewell, Assuming `arr` is like `[ arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], ... ]` when I call  `arr.splice(0, 3, result);`. I am cutting the first three elements of `arr` (i.e. `[ arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]]`) and replacing it with `[result]`. So after calling this `arr` becomes `[ result, arr[3], arr[4], ... ]`. The function `calculate` in the recursive approach only calculates the first operation of `arr`: it only takes care of the first three operations (thus the 0-2 slicing)...

Comment: ...In your code you wanted to cut and replace the elements of `arr` in one go with a `for` loop but that doesn't work so well because you can't loop an array that you're changing the structure off.